# O que significa PSR?

Tags: php

Olá pessoal recentemente encontrei um termo chamado PSR na area de PHP, mas o topico não foi muito esclarecedor em definir o real significado da palavra PSR, vi que ele estava relacionado com a area de Orientaçao a Objetos, fiz uma pesquisa no google e não encontrei muita coisa, acredito que pesquisei pelos termos errados.

Mas enfim, alguem poderia me explicar o significado do PSR e sua real aplicação?

Comment: Certeza que é SRP? naõ é [PSR](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/) ?

Comment: realmente pergunta editada

Comment: LOL eu achei que era sobre `single responsibility principle`.

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/128330/psr-7-e-a-imutabilidade

Comment: Consulte esta guia: [Introduction to PSR-1](http://www.independent-software.com/introduction-to-the-php-standard-recommendation-psr-1/). Explica o que é PSR.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As PSR (do inglês *PHP Standards Recommendation*) são especificações de projetos propostos pelo [PHP-FIG](http://www.php-fig.org/) (PHP Framework Interop Group), um grupo composto por representantes de expressivos projetos em PHP.

Esses padrões tem como objetivo facilitar a reutilização de código entre os diversos projetos que implementem determinado padrão.

Um exemplo é a [PSR-3](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-3/), que sugere uma especificação para Interface de Logs de Aplicação. Qualquer projeto que suporte a PSR-3 pode simplesmente substituir o módulo de logs por outro compatível que também suporte a PSR-3 sem nenhum impacto no projeto original (Ai temos a ideia da interoperabilidade entre os projetos).

Além do padrão de Logs, existem PSRs para implementações de [autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php) ([PSR-0](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-0/) e [PSR-4](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/)), sugestões de estilos de código, como posição de chaves, indentação ([Usar tabulações ou espaços?](http://www.jwz.org/doc/tabs-vs-spaces.html)) ([PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) e [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/)).

Existem também propostas em draft para padronização dos docblock de documentação ([PSR-5](https://github.com/phpDocumentor/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/phpdoc.md)) e uma interface para requisições HTTP ([PSR-7](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/proposed/http-message.md))

Mais informações leia o [FAQ](http://www.php-fig.org/faq/) e visite o [repositório no GitHub](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards) com os padrões já aceitos pelo grupo.

---

É importante lembrar que a adoção desses padrões no seu projeto é **opcional**.

Ninguém é obrigado a implementar funcionalidade "X" de certa maneira, porém é recomendado implementar a partir de um padrão já conhecido e adotado pela comunidade para não causar dores de cabeça futuras com seu código.

Comment: Agora sim matou minha curiosidade! :) Nem o site com as PSR explica o que quer dizer a sigla! (ou eu que não vi?)

Comment: @bfavaretto com seu comentário fiquei na dúvida sobre o real significado :) Vou perguntar no irc pra ver se é isso mesmo.

Comment: é isso mesmo...

Comment: Obrigado pelo double-check

Comment: Fyi: vão incluir no FAQ o significado: https://github.com/php-fig/php-fig.github.com/pull/120

Comment: Então, basicamente, as PSR são interfaces que devem ser implementadas pelas classes da minha aplicação? Devo usar os mesmos nomes propostos (para classes, funções, ...) ou uso o que eu quiser?

Comment: @GuilhermeCostamilam algumas são interfaces já prontas, que você pode incluir no seu projeto via composer https://packagist.org/packages/psr/ ... outras são recomendações de code style, docblocks, etc

Answer (score 8):

Achei uma resposta:

O PHP Framework Interoperability Group é um grupo formado por membros com poder de voto e que representam frameworks PHP e membros não votantes que podem participar e que definiu, até o momento, três padrões: PSR-0, PSR-1 e PSR-2.

A norma PSR-0, dita a respeito de autoloader. A PSR-1, de normas básica de códificação e a PSR-2, vai além e do básico de normatização do PSR-1.

Como acessar o guia de estilos PSR

Via URL, através de

```
PSR-0: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md
PSR-1: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-1-basic-coding-standard.md
PST-2: https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-2-coding-style-guide.md
```

Via Git, recomendo

```
git clone git://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards.git
```

Comment: Não precisa clonar, para consulta utilize o [site](http://www.php-fig.org/) que é a exata representação do github.

Comment: perfeito acabei não editando muito foi diretamente o que achei

Comment: Complementando: O quarto padrão já foi definido (PSR-4), que descontinua o PSR-0 para autoloading. E existem mais 3 em draft. PSR-5 para Documentação de código, PSR-6 para implementação de cache e PSR-7 para interface de requisições HTTP.