# Extensão 'Inc' e MVC no PHP

Tags: php, mvc, extensão

Eu sei que não é obrigatorio usar os codenomes `inc` e `class` no nome dos arquivos, mas por questão de organização mesmo é recomendado.

A duvida se deve ao fato de o codenome `class` é fácil entender que se trata de um arquivo de `classe`, mas o codenome `inc` que é de `include` é confuso, isso porque no MVC o uso deles é ideial no diretorio control ou deve ser usado apenas em arquivos como autoload por exemplo?

Porque ao meu ver, os arquivos no `control` também deveriam usar esse codenome visto que eles fazem `includes`, realizando a ligação entre o `view` e `model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nomenclatura dos arquivos é indiferente em relação a MVC ou a quaisquer design patterns.

Incluir ".inc" e ".class" era uma prática antiga que mesmo muitos programadores PHP antigos discordavam do uso.

Basicamente, essas letras apenas ajudavam a identificar que tipo de arquivo era aquele. Se possuia o ".inc" na nomenclatura, significava que era um arquivo de inclusão, ou seja, não deveria executá-lo diretamente. Ídem para os tipos ".class".

Há também os tipos ".func" e ".cons", para funções e constantes, respectivamente e provavemente deve existir outros, mas são esses os mais conhecidos.

Normalmente esses arquivos deveriam ficar numa pasta de acesso privado, não acessível pelo usuário. Mas nem todos poderiam seguir essa recomendação devido N motivos. Falta de conhecimento ou recursos (o host não permitia).

No geral, encontrará nomenclaturas do tipo

```
file.inc.php
file.class.php
file.func.php
file.cons.php
```

Alguns omitem o `.php` do final, mas isso sim pode ser uma péssima ideia pois pode expor os códigos em público se o ambiente não estiver bem configurado.

Sistemas antigos e muito usados atualmente, como o PHPMyAdmin, ainda utilizam dessa prática.

Vale salientar que não é também uma má prática. É mera questão de opinião/escolha de quem cria o projeto. O importante é o projeto ser bem escrito, bem documentado e organizado. A nomenclatura pouco importa desde que saiba o que está fazendo.

Comment: Perfeita explicação, era exatamente isso que queria saber, vlw

Comment: Resposta de ouro! É uma pena que tão poucas pessoas estejam interessadas em boas práticas.

Answer (score 3):

Não `inc` não é obrigatório e nem é um padrão de fato, na verdade existem padrões melhores como o http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/, basicamente quem usa composer usa PSR-0 e PSR-4.

Outra coisa, MVC **não tem nada haver** com PHP ou Web, MVC é um modo de organizar as coisas e já existia antes das aplicações web e não é o único tipo de *design pattern* que existe.

> Se for olhar cada framework que existe popular, que usam MVC para organizar, cada uma usa o "MVC" a sua própria distinta maneira, na verdade na maior parte dos framework organizar seguindo o Model, Controller e View é quase opicional em pelo menos um dos casos, então nisto cabe o seu entendimento de que algo que não é uma "classe" ainda sim pode ser MVC.

Um detalhe, mesmo que você queira usar `.inc` isso poderá deixar os seus scripts visíveis para quem navega, pois servidores contratados e hospedagens geralmente não tem tal extensão configurada para ser interpretado como um script php, então se a pessoa navegar assim:

```
http://site/foo/bar.inc
```

Ela irá conseguir ver o source do teu arquivo, ou seja qualquer um poderá saber como o seu script foi feito e poderá até se aproveitar disto para obter dados como senhas de banco ou encontrar brechas de segurança para explora-las.

### No PSR-0 e PSR-4

O PSR-0 foi descontinuado, recomendo só usar o PSR-4, em ambos as classes e frameworks ficam dentro da pasta padrão geralmente, e estas pastas são organizadas se baseando no namespace da classe, veja esta resposta que citei como exemplo:

- [Como funciona [modus operandi] o autoload em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/91512/3635)
- [O que significa PSR?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32295/3635)
- [O que é spl_autoloader_register em PHP?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88023/3635)
- [Classe autoload PSR4](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91493/3635)

> Vou editar e colocar mais links, tem muita coisa aqui no site sobre isso

Comment: Sobre existir outros padrões e MVC não ter a ver com web eu já sabia, minha dúvida era referente ao uso da extensao inc com uso do MVC, sobre as PSR eu já havia lido algumas coisas, mas não achei nenhum conteúdo mais completo explicando as diferenças de cada uma etc